# mysql relation slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli(//editted out db credentials);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "SELECT m.ID, m.Title, GROUP_CONCAT(a.Title) AS Artist
FROM mp3s m
LEFT JOIN artist_relations ar ON ar.mp3ID = m.ID
LEFT JOIN artists a ON a.ID = ar.artistID
GROUP BY m.ID
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 0,30;
";

if($result = $db->query($sql)){
echo "<table>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td>".$row['Title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Artist']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";  
}
echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

This query working correctly, but the speed is very slow.

This database has 3 fields:

```
`artists` : ID , Title
`mp3s` : ID , Title
`artist_relations` : mp3ID , artistID
```

i need this:

```
row1: titlemusic1 - artist1 , artist4 , artist5
row2: titlemusic2 - artist1
row3: titlemusic1 - artist3 , artist8
row4: titlemusic1 - artist9 , artist10
...
```

mp3s , artist & artist_relations each have more than 20000 records

```
EXPLAIN SELECT m.ID, m.Title, .... :
    id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
    1   SIMPLE  m   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    23718   Using temporary; Using filesort
    1   SIMPLE  ar  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    24337   
    1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   ganools_rj.ar.artistID  1
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `artist_relations`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artist_relations` (
  `artistID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mp3ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `artists`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artists` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(155) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9005 ;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `mp3s`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mp3s` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  `imageURL` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  `mp3URL` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  `Lyric` text,
  `album` varchar(155) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plays` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pubDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22936 ;

---

Comment: What columns have indexes? You can run your query with `EXPLAIN` in the front of it and the output will give you an idea of what's going on. `EXPLAIN SELECT m.ID, m.Title, ....`

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any field used in a decision context (e.g. where, join, order, case, etc...` should have an index on it.

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT m.ID, m.Title, .... :
    id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
    1   SIMPLE  m   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    23718   Using temporary; Using filesort
    1   SIMPLE  ar  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    24337   
    1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   ganools_rj.ar.artistID  1

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of these tables. If you have actually defined the foreign key constraints, indexing will be enforced and it will be performant.

Comment: show create table inserted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try create index for artist_relations.mp3ID, artist_relations.artistID and mp3s.ID. See [CREATE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Please explain more :(

Comment: If you use the artist_relations.mp3ID, artist_relations.artistID and mp3s.ID attributes in JOIN, GROUP BY or ORDER BY, is desirable to create indexes for these attributes. Be careful, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744038/decision-when-to-create-index-on-table-column-in-database) discussion.

Comment: my english is very badddd, can you get me code to run ? :(

Comment: ALTER TABLE artist_relations ADD INDEX (mp3ID);
ALTER TABLE artist_relations ADD INDEX (artistID);
ALTER TABLE mp3s ADD INDEX (ID);